# Do not receive token from curl request on PayPal

Tags: curl, paypal, token, sandbox

**Issue**:
I am not receiving a token from PayPal Sandbox.

**Notes**:
I have signed up.  I have a clientid and secret code.
I have tried to log in to my Linux server at my house and use curl via Putty.
I have tried to log in to my Linux web hosting server via Putty and use curl.
I have even tried manually adding -d "response_type=token" or just response_type="token" and various combinations to try to follow the instructions on the references URL below (even though the sample provided doesn't have response_type because the instructions call for it).

**Code Used for Request**:
curl https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
 -H "Accept: application/json" \
 -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
 -u "EOJ2S-Z6OoN_le_KS1d75wsZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp:EClusMEUk8e9ihI7ZdVLF5cZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp" \
 -d "grant_type=client_credentials"

**Expected Sample Response**:
{
   "scope":"https: //api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* https: //api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card https: //api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.*",
   "access_token":"EEwJ6tF9x5WCIZDYzyZGaz6Khbw7raYRIBV_WxVvgmsG",
   "token_type":"Bearer",
   "app_id":"APP-6XR95014SS315863X",
   "expires_in":900
}

**Reference URL's**:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/

**Question**:
How do I receive a token for the sandbox so that I can start practicing calls to PayPal? I receive no response after submitting the curl request.  It simply goes to the next line with no error.

I was not allowed to put this in to the comments.
**Result with Verbose**:
[root@host ~]# curl https:// api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token -v \

> -H "Accept: application/json" \
>   -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
>   -u "clientid-removed: secret-removed" \
>   -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
>   * About to connect() to api.sandbox.paypal.com port 443 (#0)
>   *   Trying 173.0.82.78... connected
>   * Connected to api.sandbox.paypal.com (173.0.82.78) port 443 (#0)
>   * Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
>   *   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
>     CApath: none
>   * NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)
>   * SSL connection using SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
>   * Server certificate:
>   *       subject: CN=api.sandbox.paypal.com,OU=PayPal Production,O="PayPal, Inc.",L=San Jose,ST=California,C=US
>   *       start date: Sep 11 00:00:00 2012 GMT
>   *       expire date: Sep 17 23:59:59 2013 GMT
>   *       common name: api.sandbox.paypal.com
>   *       issuer: CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G2,OU=Terms of use at https:// www.verisign.com/rpa (c)09,OU=VeriSign Trust Network,O="VeriSign, Inc.",C=US
>   * Server auth using Basic with user 'clientid-removed'
>   POST /v1/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
>   Authorization: Basic
>  QVVCOHdoQXZyT0pMbWswWjNyd0lYdkFsR0hvWTdBQld5bXluQ1lPRk13TGVMYU1KbTRvSXNDaWZqV3REOiBFTTZkdUJCYmhBUVlTbkliQWhGRTJtU0Zoc0E0R2ZYYWw0c253TEh1NkszOFloVGs1dlROa2pTSHVtUDQ=
>   User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.13.1.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.2.2
>   Host: api.sandbox.paypal.com
>   Accept: application/json
>   Accept-Language: en_US
>   Content-Length: 29
>   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   
>   < HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
>   < Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
>   < Date: Sat, 16 Mar 2013 14:21:09 GMT
>   < Content-Length: 0
>   < Connection: close
>   <
>   * Closing connection #0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that it is working now. PayPal must have had a glitch and there was nothing wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Could be numerous issues.

1) try.. -v ..after curl to see if that prints out a response for you.

2) not sure if you meant this or not but the user and pass you are showing in your example code isn't the user and pass PayPal probably assigned you,  you will need to replace them.

3) is curl setup on your home computer or enabled on your hosting service?

Comment: I was not allowed to post the results in the comment section so I edited the page above.  I did indeed replace my username and password with the examples in the book.  Curl is set up at home and at the hosting service.  However at home I have to use -k to ignore wrong ssl's.